# Why am I getting Listen Loop Bad File Descriptor errors on my machine but not anyone else's machine when specific code is enabled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently working on a project to enable database backed configurations in the frontend of our application. These need to be loaded after application initialization, so I created a module to load them and added a call to it in environment.rb, after Rails.application.initialize!.

The problem is that when this code is enabled, my console gets flooded with listen loop errors with bad file descriptors like:

```
2020-01-24 09:18:16 -0500: Listen loop error: #<Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor>
/Users/fionadurgin/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/server.rb:383:in `select'
/Users/fionadurgin/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/server.rb:383:in `handle_servers'
/Users/fionadurgin/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/lib/puma/server.rb:356:in `block in run'
```

When I disable either the call to the ConfigurationLoader or the methods I'm calling on the model, I no longer get these errors.

The rub is that I can't reproduce this issue on another machine, or in specs. I've tried on two other laptops and on one of our staging servers and they work perfectly with the ConfigurationLoader enabled.

I've tried restarting my computer, working from a freshly cloned repository, and setting all the file permissions for the application to 777. Nothing has worked so far.

Here's the ConfigurationLoader module:

```
module ConfigurationLoader
  # Overrides client default configurations if frontend configurations exist
  def self.call
    Configurations::ImportRowMapping.override_configurations
  rescue ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError => e
    log_no_database_error(e)
  rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
    log_statement_invalid_error(e)
  rescue Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError => e
    log_connection_error(e)
  end

  def self.log_no_database_error(error)
    Rails.logger.warn(
      'Could not initialize database backed configurations, database does '\
      'not exist'
    )
    Rails.logger.warn(error.message)
  end

  def self.log_statement_invalid_error(error)
    Rails.logger.warn(
      'Could not initialize database backed configurations, table does '\
      'not exist'
    )
    Rails.logger.warn(error.message)
  end

  def self.log_connection_error(error)
    Rails.logger.warn(
      'Could not initialize database backed configurations, could not '\
      'connect to database'
    )
    Rails.logger.warn(error.message)
  end
end
```

The call in environment.rb:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'
require_relative 'configuration_loader'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
ConfigurationLoader.call
```

And the model method being called:

```
def self.override_configurations
      return unless any?

      Rails.application.client.payroll_service_file.payroll_service_file
        .mappings = all.to_a
    end
```

I'll note here that I get the errors when either the guard clause or the assignment are enabled.

Anyone have any ideas about what's going on? I'm about at my wits' end.

Comment: I had to update my `puma` gem from `4.x` to `5.x` and then removed `preload_app!` from `config/puma.rb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm still not sure on the exact cause of the problem, but the solution was to move the configuration loader call out of environment.rb and into an after_initialize block in application.rb.